# Accessing instance attributes that start with a certain string

Tags: django

In my view, I'm trying to blank/delete a number of fields that start with `real_`.

I can do something like:

```
plan = get_object_or_404(Plan, pk=self.kwargs['plan_id'])
plan.real_time = None
plan.real_date = None
plan.real_comments = None
plan.real_whatever = None
....
plan.save()
```

However I guess there must be a way to do this programmatically. All I'd need to do is access the names of the the fields, compare whether it indeed starts with `real_` and then update that field.

I'm using `get_fields()` ([as per the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model)). I'm not sure though how to do the last part though.

Following is the code of my view:

```
plan = get_object_or_404(Plan, pk=self.kwargs['plan_id'])
plan_fields = plan._meta.get_fields()
for field in plan_fields:
    if field.name[:5] == "real_":
        plan.<not sure what to do here> = None
plan.save()
```

I guess I must be overlooking something small. Any pointer?

Using Django 1.9.

Comment: See if the built-in getattr() function will get you what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if field.name[:5] == "real_":
    setattr(plan, field.name, None)
```

Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something nice and neat like this:

```
plan = get_object_or_404(Plan, pk=self.kwargs['plan_id'])
real_fields = [field for field in plan._meta.get_fields() if field.name.startswith('real_')]

for field in real_fields:
    setattr(plan, field, None)
plan.save()
```

This is partially opinion based, but I feel that the use of the list comprehension and `.startswith()` are slightly more Pythonic.